# htaccess for own php mvc framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Good Morning, 
I'm building my own php framework. I would want that all request pass to index.php file except request to js css jpeg, jpg, png file. So I want that a module independently to others has own assets folder with css images and js file.

The Structure is something similar:

```
application
   module1
     models
     controllers
     templates
         assets
             css
             images
               test.jpg
               hello.png
             js

         view1.html.php
         view2.html.php

   module2
     models
     controllers
     templates
         assets
             css
             images
               test.jpg
               hello.png
             js

         view1.html.php
         view2.html.php
  core
    here is core file framework

  index.php
```

How Can I do it?

**Update**

My modules are under application folder. assets folder must be public.
I want a simple small url like **www.example.com/module1/images/test.jpg**

instead long

**www.example.com/application/module1/templates/assets/images/test.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite everything to index.php, excluding the contens of some folder, e.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(css|images|js)/
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

All files under the folders /css, /images, /js won't be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the default .htaccess of zf works well for this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [example.htaccess](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.2/master/example.htaccess) from [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/):

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Should be usable, if you just remove the line about protecting application and system files. Instead just make sure those files don't do anything on their own. In Kohana that is solved by defining a constant in the index.php, which is then checked for at the beginning of all files which should not be accessible from outside.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
```

Comment: I comment line "RewriteRule protect application" now at www.example.com/application/module1/templates/assets/images/test.jpg I can see the image. For direct access to core file framework and other file I can put constant control as Kohana. How can I Have a more simple url /module1/images/test.jpg instead all /application/module1/templates/assets/images/test.jpg ? –

Comment: @NicolaPaganotti Move the files maybe? No need to have it all in an application directory if you're not using it for anything...?

Comment: I would probably also ask myself what I'm doing all this for... Why not just use Kohana or a different MVC framework to begin with? Or at least, what makes these modules of yours so separate, if they are to belong to the same application?

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to work on my own framework and found the site below very useful.  It covers .htaccess and all other aspects of setting up a basic MVC framework.

http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/

I have rewritten all the database stuff for PDO, tweaked the default routing and changed some of the functions but found it very useful and certainly worth a read.